# What does "a cloud pass across her gaze" mean?

Tags: meaning, samuel-shem, the-spirit-of-the-place

From the novel *The Spirit of the Place* by Samuel Shem:

> Selma stared at him. He saw **a cloud pass across her gaze.** She sighed. "Orville-doll, there's nothing else but this."

What does "a cloud pass across her gaze" mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This phrase is a less-common variant of a common metaphor which uses cloudy weather to represent **negative emotion visible in a person's face**. Here are some dictionary sources to demonstrate some other variants of this metaphor:

> If a person's face clouds over, they suddenly look unhappy or worried:
> *At the mention of her dead husband, her face clouded over.*
>
> <sub>-- [Cambridge Dictionary, **cloud over**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cloud-over), meaning 2</sub>

> Used to refer to a state or cause of gloom, suspicion, trouble, or worry.
> *‘the only cloud on the immediate horizon is raising a mortgage’*
>
> A frowning or depressed look.
> *‘a cloud passed over Jessica's face’*
>
> <sub>-- [Lexico, **cloud**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cloud), meaning 2</sub>

> If your eyes or face cloud or if sadness or anger clouds them, your eyes or your face suddenly show sadness or anger.
> *[literary]*
> *Trish's face clouded with disappointment.*
> *As he looked at Katherine, great sorrow clouded his eyes.*
>
> <sub>-- [Collins Dictionary, **cloud**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cloud), meaning 6</sub>

Comment: My feeling is that the metaphor is for a cloud passing in front of the Sun. Suddenly it gets darker and colder for a moment.